# Can Locale identify country by currency code?

Tags: ios, swift, locale

I was looking for that answer in here, and also on official documentation, but I can't find the answer for that. I've got currency codes (e.g. "EUR"). I need to get country code (e.g "EU"). So I've seen that I can do it inversely (getting currency code by using country code), but I was trying to change this solution for my needs, and I got nil as result. Also I know I can use simple solution - remove last letter from currency code to get country code (It works for most cases from my API data, but not everywhere) - but I feel this approach is not safe. So my question is like in title: Can I identify country from currency code by using Locale?

Here is my approach:

with NSLocale

```
extension NSLocale {

   static func currencySymbolFromCode(code: String) -> String? {
      let localeIdentifier = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.currencyCode.rawValue : code])
      let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeIdentifier)
      return locale.object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode) as? String
}

}
```

with Locale

```
extension Locale {    
  static let countryCode: [String: String] = Locale.isoCurrencyCodes.reduce(into: [:]) {
        let locale = Locale(identifier: Locale.identifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.currencyCode.rawValue: $1]))
        $0[$1] = (locale.regionCode)
    }
}
```

Comment: How should that work? As an example, the Euro (EUR) is the currency of 19 different countries. The US dollar (USD) is the currency of multiple countries as well.

Comment: “EU” is not a country.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Maybe I will explain a little bit more what I want to achieve. I want to get flag for given currency - e.g. if you use unicode with EU then you get european union flag. And I need that flag for every currency (or if there isn't, return empty string or nil). I've got the code for getting this flag for given regionCode, but I have to get that region code from currency code

Comment: What I've done, and probably what most apps that show flags for currency, is to name currency images after the currency code. Simple. No need to attempt to map a currency code to anything else. Have the "EUR" currency code? Then load an image named "EUR.png". Have "USD", then load "USD.png".

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @AamirR is a bit not accurate.

- EUR != PL, PL = PLN = Poland
- USD != CA, CA = CAD = Canada

In majority of cases (with some exceptions), first 2 letters of currency code = ISO 3166-2 country code:

- PLN = PL = Poland
- GBP = GB = Great Britain
- USD = US = United States of America
- AMD = AM = Armenia
- CZK = CZ = Czech Republic
- BRL = BR = Brazilia

and so on ...

So if you have currency codes you can get country names (with 99% accuracy) as follows:

```
let currencyCode = "USD"
let countryCode = String(currencyCode.prefix(2))
let countryName = Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: countryCode)
        
print(countryName)

Optional("United States")
```

However, as some commented above, EU for example, is not a country, and looks like in your specific case you do not need a country flag, you need "currency flag", so for EUR you will display EU flag, which is correct, as you cant determine which EU country flag to display - France, Germany, etc ... so this approach might work for mapping currencies to countries flags.

Though there are some exceptions, in terms of first 2 letters of currency code not matching first 2 letters of country name, from ISO 3166-2 country code perspective, they still match:

- CHF = CH = Switzerland
- HRK = HR = Croatia
- DKK = DK = Denmark

... and so on

The other interesting pattern is that first 2 letters of currency codes, would usually match country internet domain, but again, there are some exceptions from this too.

Answer (score 0):

A currency can be associated with multiple countries, you should create your own custom data implementation, such as following json

```
{
"EUR":"PL",
"USD":"CA"
}
```

Create a file in your Xcode project and name it for e.g. `data.json`, and paste such JSON as above, finally use following method

```
func getCountryCode(currency: String) -> String? {
    var countryCode: String?
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")!
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: String]
        countryCode = json?[currency]
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return countryCode
}
```

**Usage**

```
if let countryCode = getCountryCode(currency: "EUR") {
    print(countryCode)
}
```

Comment: I thought about this approach and this is correct, but I was hoping, that I can do it without additional file (like this json), which will be more simple and elegant way in my opinion. But maybe it's not possible and that would be the best solution.